# Apt-get install -y

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, bash

When you run the command`sudo apt-get install -y Vivaldi`
Vivaldi being an example, but what does the

```
`-y`
```

Argument achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It basically stands for "yes", without it a prompt would appear before the download starts asking you if it is ok to install X and Y (maybe as dependencies) and occupy Z amounts of space. With the -y all answers default to yes and the installation procedes uninterrupted. I personally never use it because I want to know exactly what is being installed.

Comment: Well said. It's an important protection. Smart users read the output before agreeing to apt's proposal.

Comment: @dsSTORM + others , perfect just the answer I was looking for, makes sense to not use this method if you want to know exactly what’s being installed, nice1

Comment: Skipping prompts is more common in automated scripts which would otherwise hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

It means, that `apt-get` won't ask for confirmation, but assumes yes to all questions.

See `man apt-get`:

> ```
>   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>        Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
>        package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
> ```